# How to add an array property in an object constructor?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

```
const myCountry = function (country, capital, language, population) {

     (this.country = country),

     (this.capital = capital),

     (this.language = language),

     (this.population = population),
 
     (this.neighbours = []);
   
};

const Utopia = new myCountry("Utopia", "rabat", "arabic", "18 million", [
  "algeria",
  "tunisia",
]);
```

Comment: Add an [optional `neighbours` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) to the constructor, eg `function MyCountry(country, capital, language, population, neighbours = [])` and use `this.neighbours = neighbours`

Comment: thanks! it works, forgot the parameter

Answer (score 1):

use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
class myCountry {
  constructor(country, capital, language, population, neighbours) {
    this.country    = country
    this.capital    = capital
    this.language   = language
    this.population = population
    this.neighbours = [...neighbours]
  }
}

const Utopia = new myCountry('Utopia', 'rabat', 'arabic', '18 million', ['algeria','tunisia'])


console.log( Utopia.neighbours )
```